# I use fetch to receive data from an API. How can I pass the data to PHP?

Tags: php, fetch-api

What I want is to set the value of tipster `opentips` and `profitallseason` equal to the to the picks and win I receive from the API for each user. The structure of the data inside it are

```json
[  {"user": "cryptosniper", 
    "profitallseason": 197, 
    "profitperseason": [{ "2021-2022": 197 }], 
    "opentips": 4 
    }
]
```

So what I want is for every user to dynamically change the `$value_tipster_opentips` and `$value_tipster_profitallseason` based on the values of the API. The code that I came up with until now is the following. I don't know how to pass the data from fetch to PHP.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'tipster_infos');

function tipster_infos(){
    $getArgs = array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hide_empty'    => false
    );
    
    $categories = get_terms( 'tipster', $getArgs );
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        
        $value_tipster_user = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'tipster-user', true );
        $value_tipster_opentips = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'tipster-opentips',true );
        $value_tipster_profitallseason = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'tipster-profitallseason', true );
        
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
            fetch('https://metakomhsh.gr/betprgonostika/betapi.json', 
                    {method: 'GET', // set FETCH type GET/POST
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for(info of data) {
                    if (info.user == '" . $value_tipster_user . "') {
                        $value_tipster_profitallseason = info.profitallseason;
                        $vlaue_tipster_opentips = info.opentips;
                    }
            }
    });
</script>";
}
```

Comment: You'd have to make another AJAX request to your own server to pass the values. Or make the page submit a form containing those values in a hidden field, or make the browser nagivate to a URL with those values on the querystring. In other words, all the normal ways you can make your browser communicate with your server and PHP code.

Comment: But if you actually need these values in a PHP script primarily, why not simply get PHP to make the API request in the first place, using cURL? Was there a particular reason you chose to use fetch/AJAX?

Comment: @ADyson I did it that way because i don't know how to do it with php

Comment: Well now you do - you can make HTTP requests in PHP quite easily using PHP's `cURL` functions, (or using `Guzzle` - or even `file_get_contents`, if you're feeling masochistic :-)).

Comment: _I don't know how to pass the data from fetch to php._ - it doesn't work like that